# How to store attribute values of a selected object as a variable in Maya

Tags: python, select, maya

I am trying to set a code that will allow me to set a later frame as "starting value +1". I.e. if the value on frame 1 is 10, I would like to then set a later frame to 10 + 1. In order to do that, I need to get the value of each attribute and store it in a variable, and I have been stuck at the stage of using the getAttr command. I am attempting to get the name of the object using the cmds.ls command, but using that only makes Maya tell me that no objects in the scene have the name of the variable I'm storing the object name in.

My current code is:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

objectnameplaceholder = cmds.ls(sl=True)

obj_TX = cmds.getAttr("objectnameplaceholder.translateX")
obj_TY = cmds.getAttr("objectnameplaceholder.translateY")
obj_TZ = cmds.getAttr("objectnameplaceholder.translateZ")
obj_RX = cmds.getAttr("objectnameplaceholder.rotateX")
obj_RY = cmds.getAttr("objectnameplaceholder.rotateY")
obj_RZ = cmds.getAttr("objectnameplaceholder.rotateZ")
print(objectnameplaceholder)
```

the object I have selected has the name pSphere1. When I print objectnameplaceholder on the bottom line, it gives me pSphere1. However, when I run the code, it throws an error, saying that "No object matches name: objectnameplaceholder.translateX'

I'm sure it's a very simple mistake that's causing this but for the life of me, I cannot find it.

Comment: Just guessing: `cmds.getAttr("objectnameplaceholder").getAttr("translateX")`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. It looks like the issue is that it's storing it as a list or object, and the getAttr command wants a string?

Comment: Maybe `objectnameplaceholder.getAttr(...)`?